# Compile Error on VBA code to Long

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the code below. I need to run it from cell S1 to cell S5000 and everything in between. What I had done was written code for every single cell for 1 to 5000 but then when I pasted the code into the worksheet I got the message, "Compile error: Procedure too large". Is there a workaround so I can run the code for every cell to 5000 or even more if needed?

Thank you for your help!

```
Sub CopyPriceOver()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


If Range("S1") = 1 Then
Range("S1").Select
Range("S1").Select
Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver

ElseIf Range("S2") = 2 Then
Range("L2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ready"
Range("L1").Select
Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver

ElseIf Range("S3") = 3 Then
Range("L3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ready"
Range("L1").Select
Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver

.
.
.
.

ElseIf Range("S5000") = 5000 Then
Range("5000").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ready"
Range("L1").Select
Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver


Else


Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver
End If
```

Comment: Use a loop? It's not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: look at looping the 1 to 5000, then say `if range("s" & x).value =range("s" & x).row then range("L" & x).value="ready"` and have the range as an argument in ScheduleCopyPriceOver if the L1 etc selection is that this procedure uses activecell.

Comment: "Procedure too large" means exactly that: the procedure is so ridiculously large that VBA's parser won't even take it. Write structured code, procedures should be no longer than a screenful, maximum. Avoid writing macro-recorder code that sprinkles useless `.Select` and `.Activate` all over the place and works off `ActiveCell` and `Selection`; learn to use loops and proper control flow. Browse the [VBA documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/topics), learn how it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like the following. However, I don't know what 'ScheduleCopyPriceOver' is, so uncomment that line. AND your first example used column 'S', but then you used column 'L'. Should they all be 'L'????

```
Dim lRow    As Long
Dim ws      As Worksheet

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For lRow = 1 To 5000
    If ws.Cells(lRow, 12) = lRow Then
        ws.Cells(lRow, 12).Select
        'Call ScheduleCopyPriceOver
    End If
Next lRow
```

Comment: Also, if your range will vary, please look up how to find the last used row on a sheet, then reference that instead of '5000'